# Will the Freestyle intersecting issue be fixed in Blender 2.8?

Tags: freestyle

I've been playing around with Freestyle lately and I've noticed that there doesn't seem to be any sort of collision detection. You would expect the intersecting points of the spheres to have lines on them.

[image: Freestyle settings by default]

I've tried doing workarounds where I used booleans to join the meshes and then go in and mark the intersecting lines as freestyle but that method isn't really scalable and it wouldn't work for animations. This is the best I could achieve using that method.

[image]

I do see other posts about this issue but my question is just wondering if this is something that will be solved in a future build of 2.8? The example is using 2.79 but I've tried the 2.8 beta and it doesn't seem to be any different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is speculation about development